# Every shape I create in Illustrator CC is going at the back of the layer

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers

I have been working for a while with Illustrator CC, and suddenly this strange behavior.
Every time I create a new shape, Illustrator locates it at the back of the layer instead of the top. This is very annoying. How can I revert this behavior?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make certain your not in "Draw Behind" mode.

The leftmost box at the bottom of the toolbar should be depressed, not the middle one.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I worked like this for 1 day and it was awful.

Comment: It has it's use, but using it for everything can be a bit disconcerting :)

Comment: Being able to choose to draw always on top or always below... it's a pretty useful thing!! Just needed to know how to use it :-)